# Why should retrieved module name should be same as the module name passed in the first argument in angular.module

Tags: angularjs, module

I have written a program which uses angular modules.
I have created a module as follows:

```
// Module A
var modA = angular.module("moduleA",[]);
//Controller A
modA.controller("AController", function($scope, $rootScope, $log){
    $log.info("In controller A");
    $scope.message = "I am in controller A";
});
```

Created some another module and controller.

Created a new angular module using above created modules as :

```
var myApp = angular.module("mainModule",["modA","moduleB"]);
```

But when I run the code, I am getting the following error:
**Uncaught Error: No module: modA**

But when I change the retrived module name "modA" to "moduleA" which is passed as first argument in module in while creating  it works. May I know the reason/explanation why it is so?

The full code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="mainModule">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/angular.js"></script>
<script text="text/javascript">

// Module A
var modA = angular.module("moduleA",[]); 
//Controller A
modA.controller("AController", function($scope, $rootScope, $log){
    $log.info("In controller A");
    $scope.message = "I am in controller A";
});

// Module B
var moduleB = angular.module("moduleB",[]);
// Controller B
moduleB.controller("BController", function($scope, $rootScope, $log){
    $log.info("In controller B");
    $scope.message = "I am in controller B";
});

var myApp = angular.module("mainModule",["modA","moduleB"]);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="AController">
<span>{{message}}</span>
</div>

<div ng-controller="BController">
<span>{{message}}</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A module is a collection of configuration and run blocks which get applied to the application during the bootstrap process.

Modules can list other modules as their dependencies. **Depending on a module implies that required module needs to be loaded before the requiring module is loaded.**

In your case you are injecting "modA"

```
var myApp = angular.module("mainModule",["modA","moduleB"]);
```

which is not declared before hence cannot be loaded.
Due to which it throws an error during "Dependency Injection".

This is happening during Asynchronous loading mechanism of VM to execute modules, because modules do nothing at load time they can be loaded into the VM in any order and thus script loaders can take advantage of this property and parallelize the loading process.

You may refer to [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's error is during Dependency Injection.  The injector uses the module/component names you specify:

```
var modA = angular.module("moduleA",[]);
```

In that case you are telling it to create a module named "moduleA" with the dependencies of no other module.  It doesn't care what you named the variable, it simply registers it by the name you give.  In fact, you don't even need to store the return value because you can chain it or retrieve it

```
angular.module('moduleA').controller('MyOtherCtrl', function()...);
```

When you call angular.module(name) with no second argument it retrieves the module by name so you can add components to it that way as well.

Comment: thanks for reply. But my doubt is, if I create the modules as mentioned above, is it necessary to give the variable name same as module name. In my case should the module declaration be like : var moduleA = angular.module("moduleA",[]);. If give var as moduleA , the code works.